# Our app using Azure to authenticate Office 365 users is not supporting 2-step authentication

Tags: azure, oauth, office365, two-factor-authentication

We have a multi-tenant Windows Azure app.  We use it to authenticate Office 365 users, and grant us access to the user's calendars.

We had a support question today saying:

```
I then click the office 365 button, am taken to
the Microsoft Office 365 login screen where it
tells me I’m already logged in with my office 365
account. I click “remain signed in with this
account”, put in my password again, then am just
shown a blank screen (and microsoft sends me a text
with my two-factor authentication code, but nowhere
to input it).
```

We did not test any 2-factor authentication users when testing our new office 365 login.  But it seems to me like there is an issue on Microsoft's side in this scenario.

Is there something special we need to do on our end ( a setting in our Azure app maybe? ) to support 2-factor authentication for our users?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special. So I can investigate, are you a web app or web API? Are you doing the auth code grant flow or client credential?

Comment: We are using the web API, and in this case, we are forcing login with the prompt attribute.  Thanks Jason, happy to answer any other questions or provide more info.

Comment: And it's the oauth grant flow.

Comment: But your code is a web app, right? I've verified that this situation definitely works, but I need to test the 'prompt=login' to be sure. It would be interesting to see if your customer can login to the API sandbox at https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/ and click on "My Office 365".

Comment: Yep a RoR web app using oauth2 and prompt=login

Comment: If your prompt=login test does not uncover an issue.  We will set our own test accounts to 2-step and test further.  That way we can give more information.

Comment: Ok. Adding the prompt=login does indeed reproduce this issue. Basically I start out with one tab opened to outlook.office365.com, and sign in with the user with two-factor auth. Then I open the web app in another tab and sign in. I get the blank screen after re-entering my password. I will escalate this to the Azure folks.